# Is this a rails memory leak?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a very simple rails application which receives a post request with 130MB worth of images at a time. These requests are handled through a controller, which simply responds with a json object saying that it received the message. That is absolutely all I am doing.

I have this app deployed on a heroku hobby dyno. Whenever I make a request, the memory consumption goes up considerably, often beyond the limits of my dyno.

[Image of the heroku metrics log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9zGD.jpg)

I would expect for memory to go back to normal after the request is received and "processed" (especially given that I am not even using the contents received).

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on?

In case it helps, here is a code snippet of the controller that receives the request:

```
class ImageUploadController < ApplicationController
def create
    params["images"].each_with_index do |base64image, index|
        # ImageUploadJob.perform_later(base64image, params["imageType"], params["profileID"], index)
    end
    params = nil
  render :json => {'result': 'Image sent for upload'}, :status => :ok
end
```

Comment: Have you tried sending one image at a time? If 130 MB is the size of the images when you send them, it is probably even greater size in the Ruby app due to the Ruby objects that represent them.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I can try doing that, but it is still doesn't explain why the memory is not released. It definitely seems like a better approach to sending the images how you suggested though!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Turns out that the Puma web server I was using was causing the problems. I could not determine the reason, but as soon as I switched to Passenger, all my problems went away.